# CPU not being fully used (bottleneck perhaps?)

Tags: cpu, performance

**I have a i3-5005u, gtx 920m, 4gb ram, windows 10 64bit (laptop).**

So during CPU intensive games, specifically Prison Architect during very intensive parts like building huge structures with 150+ workers at once, my frame rate drops to around 15-18 from 60. But i noticed that I get sudden spikes in frame rate that go to 30-35, and when I check my CPU usage it goes from 40% to around 70-80%. 
Does this mean the CPU is being bottlenecked or something?

Comment: Probably being thermally throttled.

Comment: Have a look inside your Event Viewer, you may find something in 
__Applications and Service Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Resoure-Exhaustion-Detector > Operational__ OR 
__Applications and Service Logs > Microsoft > Windows > Resoure-Exhaustion-Resolver > Operational__ 
which might give you an answer.